# Swift- Fullscreen image with user interaction

Tags: ios, swift

I realise this question has already been answered but the answer I found here:

```
@IBAction func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
newImageView.frame = self.view.frame
newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
}

func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Didn't produce any errors but didn't work, in the sense that when I tried to click on the image to bring up fullscreen in the simulator, nothing happened. I have User Interaction Enabled. 
I have posted my full code [Here](http://pastebin.com/CHd1fNmi)

Thanks for your help.

[image: Image one]

[image: Image two]

[image: Image three]

Comment: Are you saying *imageTapped()* isn't executing, and that *newImageView* doesn't appear? Or that *dismissFullScreenImage()* isn't executing?

Comment: Then it's hard to say from your PasteBin code, as everything looks fine (even the code you posted here). I'm assuming *imageTapped()* is (a) an IBAction (b) properly connected up in IB to (c) maybe a UIImageView - from the name - that uses a (d) tap recognizer. If so, does everything look correct in IB?

Comment: (a) Yes i believe so (b) I tried to connect it via the storyboard by selecting the imageview and trying to connect it to the IBAction but it does not allow to connect an outlet.

Comment: For certain specific reasons, I don't use IB much anymore. What you *can* do is set up your "original" image view (the one you have in IB) just like you have the new one - in code. DO it in *viewDidLoad()*, set isUserInteractionEnabled, and assign a tap gesture to it. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed your code from your pastebin, and everything works fine. Tap on a small UIImageView, and it shows "full screen" ... tap that image, and it goes away.

**Edit**: re-reading your comments...

*(b) I tried to connect it via the storyboard by selecting the imageview and trying to connect it to the IBAction but it does not allow to connect an outlet*

I think that's your mistake. You need to connect the Tap Gesture Recognizer to the IBAction - **not** the imageview.

Make sure when you have "Art Image" selected, this is what you see:

[image]

and, when you have the Tap Gesture Recognizer selected, this is what you see:

[image]

I kinda hope it's not this simple, but... double-check the Interaction Enabled checkbox as shown here:

[image]

Comment: I have updated my post. I seem to have the same connections as you?

Comment: I just added an edit to my answer - maybe that makes sense?

Comment: Well, hmmmm.... no, your images look like you have things hooked up right. What happens if you - for the moment - remove the Swipe Gestures? They're not connected to the image view, are they?

Comment: Nope they weren't connected to the image view. Removed them but still nothing. Could it be the sumulator?

Comment: Removing them did nothing unfortunately.

Comment: Ugh - I don't see anything wrong / different. My next step would be to remove everything... add back just the image view and tap gesture... and see if the IBAction triggers.

Comment: Could I send my application through to you? Else can I put a print line in just to check if it is triggering?

Comment: Any other advice?

Comment: Sorry - was away for a bit... are you certain you have User Interaction Enabled for your art_image UIImageView? I put up a simplified project that you can try - if it works, see if you can find anything different... https://github.com/DonMag/TapTest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136430/discussion-between-t-kearsley-and-donmag).